# Why does django-pipeline's {% compressed_js ... %} tag output each script separately?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-pipeline

I've configured pipeline as follows:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',

)

# Static files storage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'

# Pipeline JS compressor
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.jsmin.JSMinCompressor'

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'website-main': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'shared/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
          'shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
          'shared/jquery/jquery.cookie.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'pipeline-compressed/website-main.js',
    }
}
```

When I use `{% compressed_js 'website-main' %}` in my template I get a script tag for each of the 3 files configured in `PIPELINE_JS`. Shouldn't I see a single script tag with `src="pipeline-compressed/website-main.js"`.

Comment: `settings.DEBUG` should be `False`. BTW, did you run `collectstatic` command?

Comment: @falsetru - Ugh :/ thanks so much... I was working locally (so `DEBUG = True`, naturally). I did run `collectstatic`. Thanks again. Will you put that into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `settings.DEBUG` to `False` to use compressed files. Or set `settings.PIPELINE_ENABLED` to `True`.

According to [`Usage - django-pipeline`](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html), the setting checked is simply `PIPELINE`, but upon viewing the source of version 1.3.15, you'll find that the setting is in fact `PIPELINE_ENABLED`:

> The templatetags will either output the source filenames or the
>   compressed filenames, depending on the PIPELINE setting, if you do not
>   specify the PIPELINE setting, **the source files will be used in
>   DEBUG-mode**, and compressed files in non-DEBUG-mode.